# Consumir api rest Java

Tags: api, string, rest, ms-access, tokens

Me encuentro validando este servicio rest , en la ejecucion me retorna toda la información del IDP y drl Token pero cuando hace la consulta del usuario genera este error, realice un debug y efectivamente se presenta el error en esta linea segun la imagen

`ERROR Debug :  httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() = >Exception occurred in target VM: Unexpected end of file from server<`

**Error en debug**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error en consola**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi que viendo esta situacion, tengo pensado incorporar una libreria nueva  que vi en este link de referencia que dejo en la parte de abajo, para validar que funcione  y poder consumir el servicio desde `SuccessFactorConection.java` especificamente en `AQUI` debajo de la linea comentada `//LLLAMAR servicio`  es donde voy a colocar esta libreria la cual me encuentro mirando como adapto , solo que soy muy novato en este tema de servicios aun y por eso me ha tocado investigar , asi que encontre estos dos links que tiene ejemplo de libreria en cuanto al llamado a cliente pero no quiero incorporarlo con maven, ya que no pienso colocar el pom xml porque eso seria hacer el proyecto desde cero

Este es el codigo del proyecto en github ya que no me es posible publicarlo todo, espero recibir si es posible cualquier orientacion para poder ver como puedo incorporar esta libreria de acuerdo a la informacion de mi codigo,si fuese posible algun ejemplo, muchas gracias sin embargo sigo intentandolo.

**LINK REFERENCIA LIBRERIA API REST :** https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial
**LINK 2 DE REFERENCIA:** https://www.arquitecturajava.com/jax-rs-client-json/
**CODIGO DEL PROYECTO :** https://github.com/daancabo97/Entel-App.git

```
EntelApp.java

 
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entel.app;

import entel.oim.connectors.ssff.OperationsSSFF;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author jusei
 */
public class EntelApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call powershell
java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> itAttribMap = new java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>();
//itAttribMap.put("host",HOST.toString());
itAttribMap.put("port","10.12.30.131");
itAttribMap.put("username","OIMUSER");
//itAttribMap.put("password",PASS_LOGIN.toString());
//itAttribMap.put("authenticationServerUrl","https://api4.successfactors.com/oauth/token"); //Desarrollo
//itAttribMap.put("authenticationServerUrl","https://api8preview.sapsf.com/oauth/token"); //Calidad
itAttribMap.put("authenticationServerUrl","https://api8.successfactors.com/oauth/token"); //Produccion
itAttribMap.put("authenticationType","oauth_saml");
//itAttribMap.put("authorizationUrl","https://api4.successfactors.com/oauth/idp"); //Desarrollo
//itAttribMap.put("authorizationUrl","https://api8preview.sapsf.com/oauth/idp"); //Calidad
itAttribMap.put("authorizationUrl","https://api8.successfactors.com/oauth/idp"); //Produccion
itAttribMap.put("clientId","ZGMyYThlMTU0ODU4NmI0YjlhMjk2NmI0ODI0Nw");
//itAttribMap.put("clientUrl","https://api4.successfactors.com/"); //Desarrollo
//itAttribMap.put("clientUrl","https://api8preview.sapsf.com/"); //Calidad
itAttribMap.put("clientUrl","https://api8.successfactors.com/"); //Produccion
itAttribMap.put("companyId","Entel");
itAttribMap.put("grantType","urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer");
itAttribMap.put("privateKeyLocation","C:\\Vespot-Daniel\\OIM\\HCMTarget\\Certificates\\CertificadoTEST.pem");
//itAttribMap.put("privateKeyLocation","D:\\CLIENTES\\EntelChile\\Certificados\\CertificadoTEST.pem");
itAttribMap.put("proxyHost","");
itAttribMap.put("proxyPassword","");
itAttribMap.put("proxyPort","");
itAttribMap.put("proxyUser","");
itAttribMap.put("sslEnabled","true");

try {
    
   String reconUrl = "User?$expand=empInfo/jobInfoNav&$filter=(userId eq '172708684' and status in 't','f')&asOfDate=9999-12-31";
  //  String reconUrl = "EmpEmployment?$filter=startDate%20gt%20datetime'(Date)'";
      java.util.HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>> userMap;
    userMap = OperationsSSFF.getUsers(itAttribMap,
            reconUrl,
            "EmpJob=/odata/v2/EmpJob?$filter=userId%20eq%20'(Username)'&$expand=locationNav,positionNav,emplStatusNav\",\"PerPersonal=/odata/v2/PerPersonal?$filter=personIdExternal%20eq%20'(Username)'\",\"EmpEmployment=/odata/v2/EmpEmployment?$filter=userId%20eq%20'(Username)'\",\"PerPerson=/odata/v2/PerPerson?$filter=personIdExternal%20eq%20'(Username)'\",\"PerPhone=/odata/v2/PerPhone?$filter=personIdExternal%20eq%20'(Username)'%20and%20isPrimary%20eq%20'false'\",\"UserEntity=/odata/v2/User?$filter=status%20ne%20'p'%20and%20userId%20eq%20'(Username)'");
                                                        
} catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}                                                  
    }
    
}
```

```
SuccessFactorConnection.java

package entel.oim.connectors.ssff;

import entel.oim.connectors.utilities.SuccessFactorsConnection;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class OperationsSSFF {
  private static final String className = OperationsSSFF.class.getName();
  
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
  
  public static HashMap<String, Object> getUser(Map<String, String> paramMap, String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3) throws Exception {
    logger.entering(className, "getUsers");
    HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      System.out.println("Call to establish connection with SuccessFactors");
      String str1 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getSuccessFactorsConnection(paramMap);
      logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Access token: {0}", str1);
      System.out.println("Constructing the filter for active users");
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00'Z'");
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.add(5, 1);
      System.out.println("getting default filter for active users");
      paramString1 = paramString1.replace("(Date)", simpleDateFormat1.format(calendar.getTime())) + "&userId%20eq%20'" + paramString3 + "'";
      System.out.println("Calling the User service from Success Factors");
      String str2 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, paramString1, str1);
      System.out.println("Response from Success Factors: {0} " + str2);
      System.out.println("Constructing user id list");
      List<String> list = getUsersIdList(str2, paramMap, str1);
      System.out.println("Checking if user is candidate");
      if (list.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Getting the Configuration Lookup of the Original SuccessFacotrs connetor");
        String[] arrayOfString = paramString2.split("\"(\\s*),(\\s*)\"");
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling each service for the user: {0}", paramString3);
        for (byte b = 0; b < arrayOfString.length; b++) {
          String str3 = arrayOfString[b].replace("\"", "");
          String str4 = str3.split("=", 2)[0];
          String str5 = str3.split("=", 2)[1].replace("/odata/v2/", "");
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "alias: {0} | service: {1}", new Object[]{str4, str5});
          System.out.println("Setting the values of the filter");
          str5 = str5.replace("(Username)", paramString3);
          str5 = str5 + "&fromDate=" + simpleDateFormat2.format(calendar.getTime());
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Final filter: {0}", str5);
          logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling the {0} service from Success Factors", str5);
          String str6 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, str5, str1);
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Response from Success Factors: {0}", str6);
          System.out.println("Saving all the attributes of the current service for the user");
          hashMap.putAll(getAttributeValuesMap(str6, str4));
        } 
      } 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "getUser - Unexpected error", exception);
      throw exception;
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "getUser", hashMap.size());
    return (HashMap)hashMap;
  }
  
  public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> getUsers(Map<String, String> paramMap, String paramString1, String paramString2) throws Exception {
    logger.entering(className, "getUsers");
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet();
    HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      System.out.println("Call to establish connection with SuccessFactors");
      String str1 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getSuccessFactorsConnection(paramMap);
      logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Access token: {0}", str1);
      System.out.println("Constructing the filter for active users");
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00'Z'");
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.add(5, 1);
      System.out.println("getting default filter for active users");
      paramString1 = paramString1.replace("(Date)", simpleDateFormat1.format(calendar.getTime()));
      String str2 = paramString1.split("\\?")[0];
      System.out.println("Calling the User service from Success Factors");
      String str3 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, paramString1, str1);
      System.out.println("Response from Success Factors: {0}" + str3);
      System.out.println("Constructing user id list");
      List<String> list = getUsersIdList(str3, paramMap, str1);
      hashSet.addAll(list);
      System.out.println("Checking if exists more results");
      for (String str4 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getMoreCodeValues(str3); str4 != null; str4 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getMoreCodeValues(str3)) {
        System.out.println("Extracting the filter for next values");
        String str = str4.split(str2)[1];
        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Filter for next values: {0}", str);
        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling the next values from {0} service from Success Factors", str4);
        str3 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, "User" + str, str1);
        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Response from Success Factors: {0}", str3);
        System.out.println("Constructing the new user id list");
        List<String> list1 = getUsersIdList(str3, paramMap, str1);
        System.out.println("Adding the new values to the original Map");
        hashSet.addAll(list1);
        System.out.println("Checking if exists more results");
      } 
      logger.log(Level.FINE, "Found [{0}] users", new Object[] { hashSet.size() });
      System.out.println("Getting the Configuration Lookup of the Original SuccessFacotrs connetor");
      String[] arrayOfString = paramString2.split(",");
      System.out.println("Getting the details of each user");
      hashSet.forEach((String str) -> {
          HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
          logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling each service for the user: {0}", str);
          for (byte b = 0; b < arrayOfString.length; b++) {
              String str5 = arrayOfString[b].replace("\"", "");
              String[] strs = str5.split("=", 2);
              String str6 = strs[0];
              String str7 = "";
              if(strs.length >= 2) {
                str7 = strs[1].replace("/odata/v2/", "");
              }
              
              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "alias: {0} | service: {1}", new Object[]{str6, str7});
              System.out.println("Setting the values of the filter");
              str7 = str7.replace("(Username)", str);
              str7 = str7 + "&fromDate=" + simpleDateFormat2.format(calendar.getTime());
              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Final filter: {0}", str7);
              logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling the {0} service from Success Factors", str7);
              String str8 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, str7, str1);
              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Response from Success Factors: {0}", str8);
              System.out.println("Saving all the attributes of the current service for the user");
              hashMap1.putAll(getAttributeValuesMap(str8, str6));
          }
          System.out.println("Saving all the details of the curen user with all the attributes of the user");
          hashMap.put(str, hashMap1);
      }); 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "getUsers - Unexpected error", exception);
      throw exception;
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "getUsers", hashMap.size());
    return (HashMap)hashMap;
  }
  
  public static List<String> getUsersIdList(String paramString1, Map<String, String> paramMap, String paramString2) {
    logger.entering(className, "getUsersIdList");
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    try {
      System.out.println("Parsing the XML to Document " + paramString1);
      SAXReader sAXReader = new SAXReader();
      Document document = sAXReader.read(new StringReader(paramString1));
      System.out.println("Get all elements returned by the service");
      List<Node> list = document.selectNodes("//feed/*");
      System.out.println("Loop over the users in the XML");
      for (byte b = 0; b < list.size(); b++) {
        if ("entry".equals(((Node)list.get(b)).getName())) {
          System.out.println("Get the userId of the current user");
          Element element1 = (Element)list.get(b);
          Element element2 = element1.element("content");
          Element element3 = element2.element("properties");
          Element element4 = element3.element("userId");
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Adding the userId: \"{0}\" to the list", element4.getStringValue());
          arrayList.add(element4.getStringValue());
        } 
      } 
    } catch (DocumentException documentException) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "getUsersIdList - Unexpected error", (Throwable)documentException);
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "getUsersIdList");
    return arrayList;
  }
  
  public static HashMap<String, Object> getAttributeValuesMap(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    logger.entering(className, "getAttributeValuesMap");
    HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      System.out.println("Parsing the XML to Document");
      SAXReader sAXReader = new SAXReader();
      Document document = sAXReader.read(new StringReader(paramString1));
      System.out.println("Get all elements returned by the service");
      List<Node> list = document.selectNodes("//feed/*");
      System.out.println("Constructing the list of Entries");
      ArrayList<Element> arrayList = new ArrayList();
      list.stream().filter((node) -> ("entry".equals(node.getName()))).forEachOrdered((node) -> {
          arrayList.add((Element)node);
        }); 
      System.out.println("Processing the list of Entries");
      processEntryElements((HashMap)hashMap, paramString2, arrayList);
    } catch (ParseException | DocumentException exception) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "getAttributeValuesMap - Unexpected error", exception);
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "getAttributeValuesMap", hashMap);
    return (HashMap)hashMap;
  }
  
  private static Long convertLongFormat(String paramString) throws ParseException {
    logger.entering(className, "convertLongFormat", paramString);
    Long long_ = null;
    if (paramString != null && !paramString.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Parsing date...");
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(paramString);
      System.out.println("Getting Long value...");
      long_ = date.getTime();
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "convertLongFormat", long_);
    return long_;
  }
  
  private static void processEntryElements(HashMap<String, Object> paramHashMap, String paramString, List<Element> paramList) throws ParseException {
    try {
      logger.entering(className, "processEntryElements");
      System.out.println("Loop over the elements in the XML");
      for (byte b = 0; b < paramList.size(); b++) {
        System.out.println("Get the element entry");
        Element element = paramList.get(b);
        System.out.println("Get the elements of the response");
        addPropertiesValues(paramHashMap, paramString, element);
        System.out.println("Looping over all link attributes");
        List<Element> list = element.elements("link");
        for (Element element1 : list) {
          System.out.println("Checking if inline found");
          Element element2 = element1.element("inline");
          if (element2 != null) {
            String str = element1.attributeValue("title");
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Inline attribute found: {0}", str);
            System.out.println("Get the elements of the inline element");
            processEntryElements(paramHashMap, paramString + "." + str, element2.elements("entry"));
          } 
        } 
      } 
      logger.exiting(className, "processEntryElements");
    } catch (ParseException parseException) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected error - processEntryElements", parseException);
      throw parseException;
    } 
  }
  
  private static void addPropertiesValues(HashMap<String, Object> paramHashMap, String paramString, Element paramElement) throws ParseException {
    try {
      logger.entering(className, "addPropertiesValues", paramElement);
      System.out.println("Get the elements of the response");
      Element element1 = paramElement.element("content");
      Element element2 = element1.element("properties");
      List<Element> list = element2.elements();
      System.out.println("Looping over all the attributes");
      for (Element element : list) {
        String str1 = element.getName();
        String str2 = element.getStringValue();
        if (str1.toUpperCase().contains("DATE")) {
          System.out.println("Converting to Long value");
          Long long_ = convertLongFormat(str2);
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Adding Date attribute: {0}.{1} with value {2}", new Object[]{paramString, str1, str2});
          paramHashMap.put(paramString + "." + str1, long_);
        } else {
          logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Adding attribute: {0}.{1} with value {2}", new Object[]{paramString, str1, str2});
          paramHashMap.put(paramString + "." + str1, str2);
        } 
        logger.exiting(className, "addPropertiesValues");
      } 
    } catch (ParseException parseException) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unexpected error - addPropertiesValues", parseException);
      throw parseException;
    } 
  }
  
  
  public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> getNewUsers(Map<String, String> paramMap, String paramString1, String paramString2) throws Exception {
    logger.entering(className, "getUsers");
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet();
    HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      System.out.println("Call to establish connection with SuccessFactors");
      String tokenSSF = SuccessFactorsConnection.getSuccessFactorsConnection(paramMap);
      
      //LLAMAR servicio https://api8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/User?$expand=empInfo/jobInfoNav&$filter=(userId eq '172708684' and status in 't','f')&asOfDate=9999-12-31
      
        //"Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenSSF
        
        
        // AQUI
        
      
      
//      logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Access token: {0}", str1);
//      System.out.println("Constructing the filter for active users");
//      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00'Z'");
//      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//      calendar.add(5, 1);
//      System.out.println("getting default filter for active users");
//      paramString1 = paramString1.replace("(Date)", simpleDateFormat1.format(calendar.getTime()));
//      String str2 = paramString1.split("\\?")[0];
//      System.out.println("Calling the User service from Success Factors");
//      String str3 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponseNew(paramMap, paramString1, str1);
//      System.out.println("Response from Success Factors: {0}" + str3);
//      System.out.println("Constructing user id list");
//      List<String> list = getUsersIdList(str3, paramMap, str1);
//      hashSet.addAll(list);
//      System.out.println("Checking if exists more results");
//      for (String str4 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getMoreCodeValues(str3); str4 != null; str4 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getMoreCodeValues(str3)) {
//        System.out.println("Extracting the filter for next values");
//        String str = str4.split(str2)[1];
//        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Filter for next values: {0}", str);
//        logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling the next values from {0} service from Success Factors", str4);
//        str3 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, "User" + str, str1);
//        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Response from Success Factors: {0}", str3);
//        System.out.println("Constructing the new user id list");
//        List<String> list1 = getUsersIdList(str3, paramMap, str1);
//        System.out.println("Adding the new values to the original Map");
//        hashSet.addAll(list1);
//        System.out.println("Checking if exists more results");
//      } 
//      logger.log(Level.FINE, "Found [{0}] users", new Object[] { hashSet.size() });
//      System.out.println("Getting the Configuration Lookup of the Original SuccessFacotrs connetor");
//      String[] arrayOfString = paramString2.split(",");
//      System.out.println("Getting the details of each user");
//      hashSet.forEach((String str) -> {
//          HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
//          logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling each service for the user: {0}", str);
//          for (byte b = 0; b < arrayOfString.length; b++) {
//              String str5 = arrayOfString[b].replace("\"", "");
//              String[] strs = str5.split("=", 2);
//              String str6 = strs[0];
//              String str7 = "";
//              if(strs.length >= 2) {
//                str7 = strs[1].replace("/odata/v2/", "");
//              }
//              
//              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "alias: {0} | service: {1}", new Object[]{str6, str7});
//              System.out.println("Setting the values of the filter");
//              str7 = str7.replace("(Username)", str);
//              str7 = str7 + "&fromDate=" + simpleDateFormat2.format(calendar.getTime());
//              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Final filter: {0}", str7);
//              logger.log(Level.FINE, "Calling the {0} service from Success Factors", str7);
//              String str8 = SuccessFactorsConnection.getServiceResponse(paramMap, str7, str1);
//              logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Response from Success Factors: {0}", str8);
//              System.out.println("Saving all the attributes of the current service for the user");
//              hashMap1.putAll(getAttributeValuesMap(str8, str6));
//          }
//          System.out.println("Saving all the details of the curen user with all the attributes of the user");
//          hashMap.put(str, hashMap1);
//      }); 
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "getUsers - Unexpected error", exception);
      throw exception;
    } 
    logger.exiting(className, "getUsers", hashMap.size());
    return (HashMap)hashMap;
  }
}
```